# Ruby On Rails Issue in Cpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I am starting my app through cpanel, I am getting this log.

```
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:12001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
/home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (MissingSourceFile)
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rush-0.6.8/lib/rush/shell.rb:1
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rush-0.6.8/lib/rush/embeddable_shell.rb:1
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rush-0.6.8/lib/rush.rb:87
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/pixelcor/rails_apps/demo/config/boot.rb:117:in `load_gems'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/pixelcor/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/pixelcor/rails_apps/demo/config/environment.rb:17
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23
```

can any one help me to get over this error.

Comment: Do you have all of the gems required to run rails installed first? Try running `bundle install` before you start the server if you have access to the command line on cpanel.

Comment: it says bundler:gemfilenotfound i ran it as root

Comment: it still is giving me same error. I have all the required gems installed. even ran bundler and it did use all that was required. still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it fixed by putting the dependency in gemfile.local
use rb-readline